# Finding the theoretical bound of local spikes in an array

Tags: algorithm, proof, probability-theory

> You are given an arrayA[1..n], which consists of randomly permuted distinct integers.
>
> An element of this array,A[i], is said to be a local spike, if it is larger than all of its preceding elements (in other words, for all j < i,A[i]> A[j]).
>
> Show that the expected number of local spikes in A is O(logn).

If anybody can give me pointers to this question, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a statistics problem, not an algorithm problem.

Comment: Similar question on math SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1929895/compute-the-expected-number-of-records-by-time-n

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @DanielWalker I would beg to differ. Reasoning about algorithms has *everything* to do with programming. A bit more of a question for CS than the SO, however close enough for me ^^.

Comment: @DanielWalker It is an algorithms question though.

Comment: Fair enough.  It should still be on the computer science exchange.

Answer (score 2):

### It is similar to the reasoning about the quicksort time complexity.

So even though it is more about statistics, it can serve as a nice example of reasoning about algorithm complexity. Maybe it would be more suited to the CS stackexchange than statistics? That being said let's dive into the rabbit hole.

First, since all the numbers are distinct, we can ommit the part about array of random integers and simply take the integers 1, 2, ..., N without a loss of generality.

Now we can change the way of looking at the problem. Instead of **having** the array we can say that we are **choosing** a random number from the range 1..N without repetition.
Another observation is, that by choosing a number X, regardless of it being a **local spike** or not, we are disqualifying all the numbers that are lower from ever being a local spike. 
Since we are now choosing the numbers, we can thus discard all Y, where Y < X from the candidate pool. This can be done since regardless of the position for a number lower than the spike, nothing will change for the subsequent spikes. Spike always has to be bigger than the maximum of the previous elements.

So the question becomes how many times can we repeat this procedure of:

- Select a number from the pool of candidates as a new spike
- Discard all the lower numbers

Before we discard whole candidate pool(starting with the full 1..N range). Not surprisingly, this is almost the same as the expected depth of the quicksort's recursion which is **log(n)**.

A quick explanation if you don't want to check the wiki: Most of the time, we will discard ~half of the candidates. Sometimes less, sometimes more, however in the long run, the half is rather good estimate. More in depth explanation can be found [here.](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/35994/why-does-randomized-quicksort-have-on-log-n-worst-case-runtime-cost)

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way to determine the solution to this problem is the following:

Define binary random variables X1, X2, ..., Xn by

Xi = 1 if A[i] is a local spike
Xi = 0 if A[i] is not a local spike

We see that the total number of local spikes is always the sum of the Xi. And we know that

E[X1 + X2 + ... + Xi] = E[X1] + E[X2] + ... + E[Xn]

By the linearity of expectation. So we must now turn out attention to deducing E[Xi] for each i.

Now E[Xi] = P(A[i] is a spike). What is the probability that A[i] > A[j] for all j < i?

This is just the probability that the maximum element of A[1], A[2], ..., A[i] is A[i]. But this maximum element could be located anywhere from A[1] to A[i] with equal probability. So the probability is 1/i that the maximum element is A[i].

So E[Xi] = 1/i. Then we see that

E[total number of spikes] = E[X1] + E[X2] + ... + E[Xn] = 1/1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/n

This is the nth harmonic number, Hn. And it is well known that Hn ~ ln(n). This is because ln(n) <= Hn <= ln(n) + 1 for all n (easy proof involving Riemann sums, but requires a smidge of calculus). This shows that there are O(log n) spikes, on average.